# UIStackView Weight like Linear layout

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

How to design the  following layout with StackView

[image]

I know that it can be easily created without using stackview but is it possible using stackview because i have lots of ui which  already designed using stackview how can i add divider between views like above image

For that i set the following constraints

[image]

**But  run time it shows like **
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Blank black area"

Comment: see the above update question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some simple `Autolayout` `constraints` to get this kind of interface with a `UIStackView`.

The below image describe the `hierarchy and constraints` that you can apply:

[image]

Also the `Accept and Reject` buttons have `Equal Width` constraint.

**Output screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: it looking perfect in storyboard but when i run project divider is not displaying

Comment: Have you set the middle view's background to black and imageView's background to white?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the output I am getting with the same view.

Comment: Here you can find the storyboard link: https://github.com/pgpt10/Tester

Comment: Sure..Happy Coding..:)

Answer (score 3):

Since `UIStackView` uses auto layout to arrange its subviews, you can modify its behavior by creating constraints.

I assume you have three views in the stack: the accept button, the divider, and the cancel button.

Create two constraints:

1. An equal-width constraint between the accept button and the cancel button.
2. A fixed-width constraint on the divider (presumably setting its width to 1).

See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34160752/77567).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `UIStackView`s, here is how:

First, create a subclass of `UIView` to use as the class of the `UIView` in between the 2 buttons.

```
class CustomWidthView: UIView {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 1, height: self.frame.height)
    }
}
```

You only need to *override* `intrinsicContentSize`.

Now, add your 2 buttons and an empty `UIView` between them, and set the class of the `UIView` to be `CustomWidthView`. Embed your 2 buttons and the view between them in a stack view, and set the position of the stack view properly using the appropriate constraints.

Select the stack view and from *Attributes inspector*, find the property named *Distribution* and from the drop down menu next to it, select *Fill Proportionally*.

To reflect your changes in the UI Builder, select the custom width view and go to *Size inspector*, go down to the bottom of the list and you'll find a property called *Intrinsic Size*, change its value to be *Placeholder*, and from the *width* drop down menu, select *1*.

There may be a better way to achieve this, but this is the one I found for now and I'd like to find a better one.

Comment: You don't need to create any subclasses. You can just do it with constraints on the subviews. [The `UIStackView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) explicitly says “You can also fine tune an arranged view’s appearance by adding additional constraints to the arranged view.”

Comment: I agree that this is overkill, the first solution I tried was similar to the one in your answer, but for some reason, it is drawn as expected in the UI Builder, but when you run, then middle view didn't get displayed.